# DbDataReader closing by itself?

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

I have the following code:

```
        var entityConnection = (System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection)c.Connection;
        DbConnection conn = entityConnection.StoreConnection;
        ConnectionState initialState = conn.State;

        List<Jobs> list = new List<Jobs>();

        int id = 0;
 try
        {
            if (initialState != ConnectionState.Open)
                conn.Open();

            using (DbCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = sql;
                reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                int count = 0;

                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    id = int.Parse(reader[0].ToString());

                    list.Add(db.Jobs.Where(x => x.JobId == id).First());
                    //count++;
                    //if (count == 150) break;

                    reader.NextResult();
                }
            }
        }
```

and i get an error saying: "system.invalidoperationexception: invalid attempt to call NextResult when reader is closed"

but the thing is i havent closed the reader, however when i remove this line:

```
list.Add(db.Jobs.Where(x => x.JobId == id).First());
```

then all works fine! But this is useless to me as I need to populate a list object from the reader which if i can't do - then I can't read the table in! (p.s i am avoiding sqldatareader and using dbdatareader as it is associated with me using the entity framework to make the above call)

Comment: it is my entity object - but i removed this and instead tried making the list of generic type int , then did list.Add(id); in that line instead, but still got the same issue :-s

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to remove the call to `NextResult`. This method is used to advance to the next result set, not the next record. The `reader.Read()` in your while loop is enough

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried removing this line

```
reader.NextResult();
```

the `while (reader.Read())` line should be fine for reading the data.

That is how we do it using IDataReader.

Comment: thank u so much, the guy above u got there first so only fair 2 give him as the answer, but thank u SOO MUCH!

Comment: well, astander actually answered 15 seconds before me ;)

Comment: Its all good, we miss the small things some times, but many eyes do catch what a single pair miss X-)

Answer (score 1):

You're calling NextResult in the While Reader.Read loop - this is confusing. If the results returned by 'sql' are just one set of records, then NextResult will attempt to find a set batch of SQL to execute. If you just want to loop through a single set of records, you don't need anything more than the loop with Reader.Read at the top.

NextResult is only needed if your SQL contains multiple statements, like :

```
SELECT 1 AS ID;
SELECT 2 AS ID;
SELECT 3 AS ID
```

If it's just a basic SELECT, it's not going to work.